# Windows 7 32bit resolution is limited for HDTV monitor

Tags: windows-7, amd-radeon, hdtv

I have a small Magnavox HDTV that i am using to test a Frankenstein PC build.  The goal is to eventually connect to my old rear projection HDTV which supports 1080i via component input.  The goal is also not to buy anymore stuff, otherwise i will just buy a smartTV and be done.

I have a ATI Radeon HD 3450 with component out adapter YPrPb.  The monitor supports 1080p, but over analog component out, should only go upto 1080i.  I have had this working with another setup.
On this particular setup, i have Windows 7 32bit, with the latest 12.8 catalyst drivers installed.  the windows splash screen starts in 480p, then switches to 480i when the login prompt is shown.  When try to change the resolution, 720x480 is the maximum value of the slider.  I have also tried the "list all modes" and that also maxes out at 720x480.
There are two options for this monitor in the devices seciton,  Generic PNP monitor, and Generic non-PNP monitor.  Neither setting fixes this.  Any ideas on how to get 1080i?

update:  after trying old versions of drivers, and powerstrip, and creating a custom monitor ini file, nothing worked, still was limited to 480i.  I installed windows xp from scratch and installed the latest drivers, and after enabling the mode in the CCC (catalyst control center) 1080i was enabled.  So this "solves" my problem, but could not get it working in windows 7 professional with the latest drivers from amd.

Comment: It sounds like your missing a proper driver.

Comment: Yes, that is what i thought, so maybe the 12.8 version is no good.... I am currently trying an older driver

Comment: Alright. Sometimes you actually need a specific driver from the company that makes the monitor. Some monitors are not compatible with generic drivers. Also, you said this monitor was a TV correct?

Comment: The monitor is a hdtv.  It does 1024x768 over the a cable or 1080i via component.

Comment: What cable? I believe the tv needs to use either VGA or HDMI to work with your computer.

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be over the vga cable.  No hdmi on any of my units, all old stuff, trying to avoid / delay a purchase

Comment: Alright, so you are using VGA. That takes us back to the driver issue.

Comment: Vga works, the component out does not.  Im going to keep trying different versions of the driver....  I was hoping to find some info to let me hack what windows is alllowing.  Ive also tried powerstrip with no success

Comment: Okay, now I am really confused. I suggest moving this into chat and we can discuss it more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6192/discussion-between-ace-legend-and-nick)

Answer (score 0):

Component is not physically capable of 1080p. Therefore, there is no way your can activate that resolution on any device. Your going to need some new hardware.

Now apparently, there is a way to achieve 1080i resolution. But I am not sure how to do that. If anyone knows how feel free to drop in another answer. However, since you said in chat that Linux does support it, I am almost positive it is a driver issue. You should try to find information from whatever company you bought the TV from and see if they will supply drivers. If not, make sure all drivers are updated.

Comment: No drivers for tv.  I didnt need them for my othe setup, which is using nvidia and linux.  Im attempting to install windows xp instead, maybe those drivers will work better

Comment: Well, that could just be because Linux supplies the proper drivers.